# I dont understand why i am passing nil through the segue way

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CatagoryToSetDetail"]){
        BYFSetsDetailViewController *controller = (BYFSetsDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

    controller.workOut.catagory = catagory.text;
    controller.workOut.excercise = excercize.text;

    NSLog(@"passing the values %@ \n and %@ \n ",controller.workOut.catagory,controller.workOut.excercise);
}
```

for some reason controller.workOut.category is nil and i dont know how to fix it.

here is how i instantiated it in view did load

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.workOut = [[BYFWorkOut alloc]init];
NSLog(@"recieved values %@ \n and %@ \n ",_workOut.catagory,_workOut.excercise);
}
```

Thank you any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is `workOut` is a custom object? If yes you may need to instantiate it.

Comment: yes it is a custom object.I did make a property for it in BYFSetsDetailViewController.

Comment: Then try instantiating `workOut` in `init` of `BYFSetsDetailViewController`

Comment: tried doing that still not working though.

Comment: Move `self.workOut = [[BYFWorkOut alloc]init];` to `init` of `BYFSetsDetailViewController` and try

Comment: i tried that and she still be broke bro.

Comment: Init would not work here as he is not creating and instance of BYFSetsDetailViewController in his prepareForSegue method.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Have you checked that `category.text` and `exercise.text` are not nil? - as those are the values you're passing to the `destinationViewController` in this method.

Also, where have you instantiated `catagory.text` and `excercize.text` ?

**Edit**

It looks like your custom object `workOut` has not been instantiated correctly. Do this in your init or viewDidLoad method of `BYFSetsDetailViewController`

**Edit 2**

Okay I got it work like this (Not sure why, maybe someone can explain more)

In your `BYFSetsDetailViewController` make a public property of NSString (I assume, workOut is an NSString?)

Then in your prepareForSegue method do this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
 if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CatagoryToSetDetail"]){
    BYFSetsDetailViewController *controller = (BYFSetsDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

controller.myString = catagory.text;
controller.myString2 = excercize.text;

NSLog(@"passing the values %@ \n and %@ \n ",controller.workOut.catagory,controller.workOut.excercise);
}
```

Declare your strings like this: `@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *myString`

Then in your viewDidLoad method of `BYFSetsDetailViewController`

Do this:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.workOut = [[BYFWorkOut alloc]init];
self.workOut.catagory = self.myString; 
self.workOut.excercize = self.myString2; 
NSLog(@"recieved values %@ \n and %@ \n ",_workOut.catagory,_workOut.excercise);
}
```

This should solve your issue.

**Edit 3**

From Cy-4AH's answer - do this in your prepareForSegue

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CatagoryToSetDetail"]){
        BYFSetsDetailViewController *controller = (BYFSetsDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

  controller.workOut = [[BYFWorkOut alloc]init];
   controller.workOut.catagory = catagory.text;
    controller.workOut.excercise = excercize.text;

    NSLog(@"passing the values %@ \n and %@ \n ",controller.workOut.catagory,controller.workOut.excercise);
```

Remember to import `BYFWorkOut` in this viewController at the top of the file.

Comment: Yes i checked to make sure they are not nil. They are UITextfields that i declared in the .h

Comment: In your viewDidLoad method of BYFSetsDetailViewController - are you instantiating the workOut object? It will need more than just a property to work. You need to alloc / init it, too.

Comment: that i did not know. so in viewDidLoad i would just             BYFWorkOut *workOut = [BYFWorkOut alloc] init];

Comment: Something like that, yes. When BYFSetsDetailViewController loads - the property for workOut will be nil. I have updated my answer for you.

Comment: still did not fix it. I think that would be the solution if i was receiving nil but passing something legit. but i am still passing nil

Comment: Give me two mins.. doing a demo project to demonstrate it for it. In the mean time in your viewDidLoad method do this: self.workOut = [[BYFWorkOut alloc]init]; 
The code you just posted - you're creating a new instance of your object and never assigning it.

Comment: I updated my answer on how to solve it. Let me know if that works.

Comment: workOut is a custom class that has a NSString in it  but let me try this real quick

Comment: Great stuff. Try my Edit 3 in my answer - its clear.

Comment: Can you update your question with my edit 3 solution. Tested my side and it works.

Comment: My edit 2 worked for him - which is why he marked it as answered. My edit 3 - I did mention it comes from your answer - I just explained it in full.

Comment: @user3431724, edit 3 will not work if you leave `self.workOut = [[BYFWorkOut alloc]init];` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: ok eit three now works but now when i store the item in a sharedStore it is nil

Comment: Ya not really sure why edit three breaks my code but it does so edit two is the answer

Comment: Not sure why I am getting down votes, since edit 2 worked for you. Anyway, glad its working.

Comment: i know its quick and dirty but if it works it works thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

`prepareForSegue` performed before `viewDidLoad` and yours `workOut` is `nil` when you tries assign category and excersize

**Solution 1:**

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CatagoryToSetDetail"]){
        BYFSetsDetailViewController *controller = (BYFSetsDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

    controller.workOut.catagory = catagory.text;
    controller.workOut.excercise = excercize.text;

    NSLog(@"passing the values %@ \n and %@ \n ",controller.workOut.catagory,controller.workOut.excercise);
}
```

in BYFSetsDetailViewController:

```
@implementation BYFSetsDetailViewController 

@synthesyze workOut = _workOut;

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder*) encoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:encoder];
    if (self)
    {
       _workOut = [[BYFWorkOut alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"recieved values %@ \n and %@ \n ",_workOut.catagory,_workOut.excercise);
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CatagoryToSetDetail"]){
        BYFSetsDetailViewController *controller = (BYFSetsDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

    controller.workOut = [[BYFWorkOut alloc]init];
    controller.workOut.catagory = catagory.text;
    controller.workOut.excercise = excercize.text;

    NSLog(@"passing the values %@ \n and %@ \n ",controller.workOut.catagory,controller.workOut.excercise);
}
```

in BYFSetsDetailViewController:

```
@implementation BYFSetsDetailViewController 

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"recieved values %@ \n and %@ \n ",_workOut.catagory,_workOut.excercise);
}
```

Comment: so wait what do i do with this code put it in BYFSetsDetailViewController? also why do i have to encode it?

Comment: @user3431724, As I write: `prepareForSegue` performed before `viewDidLoad` and yours workOut is nil, and you assign text to nil.catagory and nil.excercise. But `initWithCoder` performed before `prepareForSegue`, so you should create workOut object inside it.